# How to reset default type layout for text frames in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles

When I'm creating a file with different text styles in InDesign, at some point I invariably notice that the software has adopted a 'standard' setting for type in a brand new text box I create. Not just Paragraph and Character styles are slapped on, but also settings like vertical centering of text, or *shudder* horizontal centering.

This feature is a returning source of huge frustration on my part. Is there a way to tell InDesign that new text frames I draw need to be styleless, settingless and completely default?

Comment: Have you tried deselecting all text frames and then selecting the [None] object style and clear its overrides? (If that’s even possible… not sure offhand if you can apply any object style with no object selected.)

Comment: I think changing the `[Basic Text Frame]` object style is the style to adjust/reset. You may need to adjust it with no document open. (This is ultimately just a guess though.)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can *attempt* to change the defaults on some (most) of the global type settings:

- Close all documents.
- Break link to styles everywhere (Paragraph Styles panel, Character Styles panel, Object Styles panel).
- Also click in these panels away from any highlighted style, to make sure they don't remain selected.
- Make all the possible settings you can for the type options, with all documents closed.
- Restart InDesign and try again.